# How to delete millions of rows from an Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-runbook

The problem I am facing now is that I have to delete over 90 million rows from an Azure Microsoft SQL database, and I cannot simply remove the table and rebuild a new one.

And that is the code I am using

```
DECLARE @NRO INT = 0; 
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    SET @NRO = @NRO + 1; 
    PRINT CONCAT(@NRO * 2000, ' ROWS DELETED.')

    DELETE TOP(2000)
    FROM AuditDetail
    WHERE Id < 25000000;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 2000 
        BREAK;
END
```

I have tried to use the Azure Runbook to finish the job, but it can only allow me to run the SQL script for 9 hours, even I set the timeout time to more than 24 hours.

**My question**: how to setup the Runbook correctly to run the script for as long as I wish, or is there the other way to finish the job? I have tried to use the Checkpoint, but it did not work, I may do it wrong :(

Thank you.

Comment: "...and I cannot simply remove the table and rebuild a new one." - Why?

Comment: What is the overall table size? How many rows will be left after the 90 million rows are deleted? What SKU is your database on? Is `Id` indexed to allow each batch to be found efficiently? What is the motivation for 2000 batch size?

Comment: [https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/04/how-to-delete-just-some-rows-from-a-really-big-table/](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/04/how-to-delete-just-some-rows-from-a-really-big-table/)

Comment: @MartinSmith I am not sure the table size, but it is about 800GB from 1000GB. The Id is indexed since it is auto increment primary key. Set it to 2000 rows because the regular delete for 90 million record will overwhelm the memory and causes the job fail.

Comment: @MitchWheat the table is used by the web application which is active 24 hours, I am not the one who built the DB, it is too risky for me to make such a big change, and delete it may cause legal issue.

Comment: How many rows does the table have? "Overwheming memory" with large batch size isn't a thing. There are two reasons for limiting batch size here. To avoid transaction log growing out of control (which shouldn't happen in Azure with ADR anyway) and to prevent lock escalation.  But second one does sound like it could cause problems to the Web application

Comment: Does the Web application only insert to it or does it read as well?

Comment: @MartinSmith just insert.

Comment: @Stu good article, so do I need to keep creating new view and keep deleting it repeatly?

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: And that article doesn’t provide any benefit vs what you are currently doing. The use of a view is only to provide an ORDER BY and it is no quicker to select a batch of rows with an ordering criteria enforced than without one

Comment: " I am not sure the table size,"  - erm, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table ....

Comment: A batch size of 2K seems a bit small for 90M rows. Try a larger size, like 100K.

Comment: @MartinSmith I dont dare  to use the COUNT command, it will take forever to get the result lol

Comment: @myname, you can get a non-transactional row count quickly with `SELECT SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.AuditDetail') AND index_id IN(0,1);`.

Comment: @DanGuzman wow, it instantly shows the result, 135,746,190. Is there a fast way to check the top 100 rows? Sometimes I want to see how it progresses.

Comment: You could just specify aa NOLOCK hint: `SELECT TOP (100) * FROM dbo.AuditDetail WITH NOLOCK ORDER BY Id;`

Comment: Thank you for all the help, it is already halfway done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track given your constraints.

I'd also recommend playing around with your batch size while monitoring the relevant metrics in your Azure SQL metrics blade. If your batch size of 2k records at a time isn't even making a blip on CPU or memory, consider stopping the query and increasing the batch size.

You might also consider a scale up depending on your SKU. If you're on the vCore or Hyperscale SKUs, you will be able to speed things up by scaling out your number of cores, then scaling them down when all delete ops are finished.

One more thing to consider if you're really risk-adverse, there are no legal hurdles, and you have budget to do so. You can create a copy of your prod database to experiment on. It's as simple as connecting to the master database and executing "Create database X as copy of Y". Doing so doesn't impact your database's performance. Then you can experiment on this copy of prod.